# How can I align an image left on desktop and center in mobile in blogger?

Tags: image, alignment, media-queries, blogger

I want to keep an image aligned left on desktop view (because I have text on the right and want them to be on the same level), but want the image to be aligned center on mobile (so that the text would show beneath the image). It's for the following address https://neprihanitulbogdan.blogspot.com/

I want to mention that I have tried several solutions such as

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 736px) {
  . img {
   margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

or this one

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {

    img {display:block;margin:0 auto;
}
```

Can anyone help, please? Any response is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to change on your website?
(https://neprihanitulbogdan.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Hi Ben, as it says in the description, I want to make the image align left on desktop and center on mobile, I wanted to use a media querie to do this...I managed to do it using this  in the html coding of the post <div class="separator" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-center: 1em;"> but have to put this manually for each post